# ASP.NET Core Web API Google Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core WebAPI (.NET 6.0)

I would like to implement Google Authentication using the guideline shared by Google on https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

My understanding of the process s that - I request a JWT from Google from my Web Client (VueJS) - send the JWT to the WebAPI to verify.

For verification, it seems I need to write some code as per the guidelines shared on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth.

Then I create a new JWT for the user using the details, role information, and claims stored in my DB and send it back to the client.

The client saves the new JWT to local storage and keeps sending it for every new API request.

The entire process feels a little like reinventing the wheel, is there a more standard method of handling the WebAPI part?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a more standard way.  You have described the standard way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

In short:

- Web client requests authentication from *your* web API.
- *Your* web API replies to the web client to redirect to the identity provider to authenticate (Google).
- Web client authenticates with identity provider, auth token is returned.
- Web client sends auth token to *your* web API.
- *Your* web API uses that token to either continue authentication for requests, or generate a *your* web API specific token that is returned to the client and used for subsequent requests

In an OAuth2 Authorization setup a 1 time use token is returned to the web client, which then sends it to *your* web API. *Your* web API uses that one time use token to request additional user identity information from the identity provider (Google).

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of Google Authentication is correct. The best practice regarding webapi using Google Authentication should also be the same.

---

**1. Register your in Google, get client_id and client_secret.**

**2. Add the services Identity, Authentication and Google in .Net core as follows. And add the attribute [Authorize()] to the APIs you want to secure.**

[AspNetCore WebAPI - Google Authentication](https://dvoituron.com/2019/08/09/webapi-google-auth/)

**3. Get `access_token` from google.**

**4. append `access_token` in your every httprequest when access your webapi.**

Comment: Well, this is the part that I do not understand in most online guides, why would I need to add Google Authentication at a global level when I need it only for one function i.e. Authenticate which would validate whether the Google Email ID is of a valid user or not. Post that everything will be authenticated from the custom JWT which I created.